# Unable to read() from gridfs with python in Windows

Tags: python, mongodb, gridfs

I use pylons framefork and store some images in the gridfs.

This code works perfect for MacOS and Linux servers

```
f = self._fs.get(ObjectId(image))
# In linux unicode u'image/jpg' raise error, thats why I use str() for content-type
response.headers['Content-type'] = str(f.content_type)
return f.read()
```

In Windows I get an error "Unable to read image". What the reason?

Comment: Can you post version numbers and bit-ness of the code involved?  Windows 7?  64-bit?  Python version and 32-bit or 64-bit?  C extensions or not?

Comment: Win7 64-bit, Python 2.7 32-bit. No C ext. In the ipython I see result of f.read(). But no image at response.

Comment: What program on Windows is giving you "Unable to read image" and what is the image?  I assume that this program will display the image if you access it directly rather than through GridFS ... have you tested this?  What if you save the file on MacOS and then just copy it through GridFS to a file on Windows ... do you get the same bytes back?  Just trying to narrow down where the problem might lie ...

Comment: This is browser response. I try to render images on site from gridfs.

Comment: What is the image? will the browser display it when it's not in gridfs? what browser is it? did you run the test tad suggested about getting the same bytes back?