# Perl, GridFS, and storing/recovering .docx files

Tags: perl, mongodb, gridfs

I'm using perl and MongoDB::GridFS (along with other mongo modules) to store and retrieve files. It works fine with .txt, but I want to store and retrieve .docx. Here is my code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use MongoDB::GridFS;
use MongoDB;
use MongoDB::Database;
use MongoDB::OID;

my $conn = new MongoDB::Connection; 
my $db   = $conn->test; #name of our local db is test...default of mongoDB
my $coll = $db->err0; #err0 is the name of the collection
my $grid = $db->get_gridfs;
my $fh = IO::File->new("wordtoyamutha.docx", "r");
$grid->insert($fh, {"filename" => "test"});

my $outfile = IO::File->new("wordtoyamutha.docx", "w");
my $file = $grid->find_one({"filename" => "test"});;
$file->print($outfile);
```

I first created a .docx called "wordtoyamutha.docx", then ran the above code with the last three lines commented out. It ran well and a new entry appeared in my MongoDB fs.files. I then deleted the .docx ran the code with all the "storing" code commented out- to be explicit these lines were commented out from the above:

```
my $fh = IO::File->new("wordtoyamutha.docx", "r");
$grid->insert($fh, {"filename" => "test"});
```

A docx appeared with the title wordtoyamutha...but when i tried to open it Word complained that it was rendered unreadable via corruption.

I don't know of any other way to retrieve files...and this is all the perl MongoDB::GridFS suggests to do...what is the trick here?

The exact error from Word appears in a dailog and says "The file wordtoyamutha cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents".

Comment: could you check the file sizes of the file before adding and after retrieving?

Comment: Sure can - same size. Both are 12.3 KB... so the data must be transferring...just grossly such that Word can't read it. Surely there is a way around this.

Comment: I tried your script with a mp3 file and when I do exactly what you do and make md5sums before and after they stay the same. Please check if the error is really your script.

Comment: Oh wow...I did my script on an .mp3 as well...loaded then reloaded, and it horribly screwed up the mp3 when i played it back...maybe it is not keeping an accurate enough account of things...again, the size was the same but huge difference in actual content, obvious via playback. How are your files when you try to open them?

Comment: The files are exactly the same(bit by bit) and both work just finde.

Comment: are the two of you on different OSs by chance? Using Word suggests OP is on Windows, maybe the other test was on a different OS? This questions also suggests some problem on Windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708288/unable-to-read-from-gridfs-with-python-in-windows

Comment: you very probably need to set binmode on your output filehandle.. $outfile->binmode()

Comment: @AsyaKamsky yeah, I tested on Linux (Fedora Core 17)

Comment: I used binmode and that DID work for the .mp3 (albeit there was slight corruption - random hiccups upon playback). The .docx's though, still won't open in Word with the same error message as mentioned. And yes I'm on Windows.

Comment: Also corrupts JPG's such that they can't be viewed by Windows photo viewer (even w/ binmode). I guess this question will be getting a bounty soon - I can't find this stuff ANYWHERE!

Comment: How about binmode on input filehandle too?

Comment: ...well good lord Oleg...that worked. Can't believe I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here is the (fully functional!) results of the help I was given:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
#Using Strawberry Perl and on Windows 7 box

use strict;
use warnings;
use MongoDB::GridFS;
use MongoDB;
use MongoDB::Database;
use MongoDB::OID;

my $conn = new MongoDB::Connection; 
my $db   = $conn->test; #name of our local db is test...default of mongoDB

my $grid = $db->get_gridfs;
my $fh = IO::File->new("cool.docx", "r");
$fh->binmode();
$grid->insert($fh, {"filename" => "docx"});

my $outfile = IO::File->new("return.docx", "w");
$outfile->binmode();
my $file = $grid->find_one({"filename" => "docx"});
$file->print($outfile);
```

Again, this is not a great script - things are hardcoded here. This pulls a docx file titled "cool" from the **same directory as the perl script**, stores it in my db "test" and then retrieves it **again in the same directory as the perl script** as return.docx. AKA return.docx will appear in the directory and be an exact copy! This is not very useful alone - but obviously if we can do this it implies we can do much more.

=======WHAT DO I NEED TO CHANGE TO MAKE THIS SCRIPT WORK FOR ME?========

The parameter name "docx" is changeable - it is how the file will be addressed in the GridFS database. Then obviously the filename is changeable. Future users will probably have to change the "my $db" line as well to

```
my $db   = $conn->name_of_your_DB;
```

If you don't know what the name of your DB is, go into the Mongo shell, type

```
show dbs
```

it gives a list of dbs. Now choose one of the listed dbs - we will call it db_you_want_to_use. Now type

```
use db_you_want_to_use
```

And change that  $db line in the script to point to the same thing you just typed, AKA:

```
my $db   = $conn->db_you_want_to_use;
```

Upon inserting a file with GridFS it creates a *collection* called fs.files. Use

```
db.fs.files.find()
```

To see the entries in your DB - AKA to check if things were properly inserted.